# What is the liftime of a literal of any type if we hold the reference of it or are passsing it to a function by rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, reference, rvalue, lvalue

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
    
void func1(int &&val) {
    
    // statements
    
}
    
int main() {
    
    const int &i = 5; //line1
    
    func1(4);// line 2
    
    return 0;
}
```

Is the lifetime of i in line 1 same as the lifetime or scope of main()? What about the liftime of the integer literal 4 in line 2, is its lifetime also same as that of main()?

Comment: Literals aren't objects, they don't have a lifetime. In each case a temporary object of type `int` is materialized, and these temporary objects are the objects whose lifetime I think you are asking about.

Comment: Yes, I want to know the lifetime of these temporary variables in the case when their reference is stored and when it isn't. Also where do literals(that you mentioned) generally reside, do they just exist in the source code?

Comment: Literals are just values. If they reside anywhere, it's probably baked into the assembly.

Comment: You can see it here https://godbolt.org/z/ETr6hexPs, (with optimizatitions off) the value 5 is compiled to a constant thats put on the stack(with optimizations off the value 5 dissapears because its not used). The same for value 4, the function just gets the value of the stack to use it.

Answer (score 3):

In line 1 the lifetime of the temporary object materialized from the prvalue `5` is extended to that of the reference it is bound to. So the temporary lives until the end of `main`, where `i`'s scope ends.

This is the general rule: The temporary is lifetime-extended to the lifetime of the first reference which is bound to it.

There are a few exceptions to this rule, namely it doesn't apply when the reference is the return value of a function, when using C++20 parenthesized aggregate initialization and in `new` expressions. In these cases the temporary lives only until the end of the full expression containing it, which is generally shorter than the lifetime of the reference.

Additionally, you must make sure that between the creation of the temporary and the reference binding only certain operations are performed on the expression referring to the object. For a complete list see [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary).

Also, when I say *the first reference*, I really mean that. If you are passing a temporary object to the constructor of another object, the reference in the constructor's parameter already counts. This way you can generally not extend the lifetime of objects by "storing" them in reference members of classes.

In line 2 it is an exception in a slightly different way. If the reference in question is a function parameter in a function call, then the temporary lives until the end of the full expression with the function call, so until the end of the line. In this case the temporary lives longer than the reference.